# What Am I? - A Riddle (GLARE AT ME, WHILE I AT YOU)

Tags: riddle

> Glare at me, while I at you
>
> Worship this familiar with glimmer
>
> While I stand in unfrequented gloom
>
> Common, still I elude avaricious hands

Comment: Is it a Pokemon??

Comment: Haha! No (but as a fan of the manga, anime and TCG, I like your guess)

Comment: "Glare At You Glare At Me" is my favorite Genesis song

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are..

> a star!

---

*Glare at me, while I at you*

> I suppose stars can resemble eyes, so when you look at them, you can imagine them looking back at you.
>
>  **Author's note:** "Glare" is a word-play. It can mean "stare", which is what you do at stars, and it can also mean "shine", which is what they do at you.

*Worship this familiar with glimmer*

> It is safe to say that everyone sees the starry night sky quite frequently. Those **glimmering** stars are quite **familiar**, are they not?
>
>  **Author's note:** The answer is a word-play too. Not only are celestial stars worshipped, but we also adore famous celebrities ("stars") with paparazzi camera flashes.

*While I stand in unfrequented gloom*

> Stars are surrounded by the dark night sky.
>
>  **Author's note:** Stars are also solitary, never visited. Celebrities could also certainly feel lonely where they are.

*Common, still I elude avaricious hands*

> There are countless stars dotting the sky, eternally out of reach.
>
>  **Author's note:** Indeed! Also, celebrities are common in general, but those who desire to personally get to know them will most often find them out of reach.

**Author's note:**

> Now I understand all the more why we call celebrities "stars"!

Comment: This answer is correct! I'll edit your answer to show the interpretation of the lines.

Comment: Haha, I love the feel when I have just posted the answer seconds ago and it's already accepted. Yes, by all means feel free to edit! :)

Comment: For the record, I like the spirit of the suggested edit ("Author's note") here a lot more than the norm of the OP insisting you add every word of their reasoning as it exists inside their head before they'll accept an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Is it

> your reflection in a mirror?

*Glare at me, while I at you*

> This is obviously what you see looking in a mirror.

*Worship this familiar with glimmer*

> appears to refer both to the familiarity of your own reflection, and the glimmer from the surface of the mirror.

*While I stand in unfrequented gloom*

> could be a reference to our inability to frequent the world we see in reflections,

*Common, still I elude avaricious hands*

> a reference to both the commonplace nature of reflections, combined with our inability to grasp something in a reflection.

Comment: This is a very good guess, and based on your hints, might be acceptable as a secondary answer to the riddle... but not the answer I had in mind. Great thinking!

Comment: I'll also add that your answer is not close to the official answer, so try something else!

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be:

> Your shadow. (I personally think the mirror answer explains the first two stanzas better though)

Glare at me, while I at you:

> This could be explained by the fact your shadow mimics your actions.

Worship this familiar with glimmer:

> your shadow spreads across surfaces, unevenly , depending on the sources of light casting it. This can make it shimmer and stuff. (And light glimmers)

While I stand in unfrequented gloom:

> You (most of the time) stand in the feet of your shadow's feet, and yet cannot frequent the space your shadow occupies. (otherwise your shadow disappears)

Common, still I elude avaricious hands:

> Shadows are everywhere, yet they are impossible to grasp/take/etc...

Comment: Some good thoughts. The "glimmer" guess was a bit far-fetched, but I especially liked your interpretation and use of the word "stand", which isn't a help to the actual answer. Good stuff!

Comment: Glimmer could be used to describe the diffraction which occurs around the edges.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be:

> A diamond

Glare at me, while I at you:

> Not sure, but the translucence of a raw diamond could be associated with a glare.

Worship this familiar with glimmer:

> Worship the stone by polishing it, till it shines

While I stand in unfrequented gloom:

> They are buried deep in the bed rock

Common, still I elude avaricious hands:

> Even the rich and greedy have a hard time getting them, and at times kill for them.

Comment: This is another great answer that fits all the clues! Good stuff! See the accepted answer for the one I had in mind.